# Azure AD: Failed to grant permission for application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am just trying to do grant permission for my application after registering with Azure AD, but I am getting this error,

Failed to grant permission for application "".

Could somebody suggest me the reason?

[image]

Comment: Are you a global admin in this tenant?

Comment: Try to **click the Notification of that error for more details**. Then you can copy the error and post it in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Grant permissions* button does administrator consent for the tenant, so you should be an admin in the Azure AD tenant to do this.

Administrator consent means that no user will be asked for consent, and thus requires higher privileges.

Edit: this was possibly changed later so the button now does regular user consent if you are not an admin. Though if the tenant has user consent disabled, you'd get this or a similar error too.